# Angular js not routing to default page after browser page refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

I have angularjs route with the following definition:

```
moduleA.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.
    when('/A',{templateUrl:'A.jsp'}).
    when('/B',{templateUrl:'B.jsp'}).
    when('/C',{templateUrl:'C.jsp'}).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/',
        templateUrl: 'A.jsp'
    });
});
```

Now, let say I click on something and it is redirected to #/C/ view. After refreshing the page, it is redirecting to view C and not to the default view.
I have to show default page after every page refresh happens.
I thought of changing the url to base url while refreshing the page, so that it can be redirected to default page. I am looking for better alternative for this through Angularjs way.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the url is something like `http://www.domain.co.il/#/C` and you refreshing the page it will return to C, to go back to the default you have to navigate to your root url like `http://www.domain.co.il/#/` or navigate to an unexisting url.

Comment: Thats the expected behaviour really. You have `http://foo.bar/#C` and reload the page or send your friend a link or bookmark it and you go directly to the expected view. You will probably need to do something in the `.run` to direct to default view on each page refresh but that's odd. I'd like to know your use case for that behaviour

Comment: @Dvir: That I know, but the actual issue is how to redirect to default page through angularjs way,

Comment: try`<a href="#/">Back yo home</a>` or with javascript `$location.path`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:
In the app.run() block inject 'window' and $location dependency and add:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
   $location.path('/');
};
```

Like @maurycy commented, If you want user to go to default page anytime a user he's comming to your application, you don't need the event.

just:

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
            if (!current) {
                $location.path('/');
            }
        });
```

in your app.run() function.

It should work

Comment: why adding event listener when he can redirect on the run which happens only when application loads?

Comment: If he comes to the app from a link with a specific URL, like `http://www.domain.co.il/#/C` I want him to go to the `C` page.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved a lot of time of mine. I was trying many other things not working.

Comment: Cool !! +1 my answer you will help me as well :)